# Java Parsing Error when running program in Eclipse

Tags: java, unix, dos2unix

I wrote an application in eclipse on Windows and i have moved it over to a Raspberry pi.  now when i try to run the application from eclipse i get an error.  `/opt/jre/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java: 1: /opt/jre/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")`

I understand from reading other questions that it is a parse error and i should run dos2unix on something. What exactly am i supposed to run it on though? the other questions are mainly script related.   I have .java files, .css files and .fxml files.

I have succesfully moved .java files before and they have worked fine.

**EDIT** as requested posted code

```
`package Lasercontroller;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jfxtras.scene.control.CalendarPicker;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;

public class LaserControllerUI extends Application {

public TwoWaySerialComm twoWaySerCom;

/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Initialise TwoWaySerialCom class
 **************************************************************************************************************************/
public LaserControllerUI() {
    twoWaySerCom = new TwoWaySerialComm();
    }

/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Initialise buttons and Components
 **************************************************************************************************************************/
@FXML
TextField userId, passwordfield;
@FXML
TextArea customStringTextArea, resultsTextArea;
@FXML
private Button openComportButton, setPresetButton, callPresetButton, startTourButton, stopTourButton,
        clearPresetButton, upButton, downButton, leftButton, rightButton, sendCustomStringButton, dateTimePickerStart, dateTimePickerEnd;
@FXML 
private Label startTimeLabel, endTimeLabel;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> baudRateComboBox, dataBitsComboBox, stopBitsComboBox, parityComboBox, comPortComboBox;
@FXML
private ComboBox<Byte> setPresetComboBox, getPresetComboBox;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // called by FXMLLoader after injecting fields
    parityComboBox.getItems().addAll(parity);
    parityComboBox.setValue("none");
    baudRateComboBox.getItems().addAll(baudRates);
    baudRateComboBox.setValue("4800");
    dataBitsComboBox.getItems().addAll(dataBits);
    dataBitsComboBox.setValue("8");
    stopBitsComboBox.getItems().addAll(stopBits);
    stopBitsComboBox.setValue("1");
    setPresetComboBox.getItems().addAll(preset);
    getPresetComboBox.getItems().addAll(preset);
    comPortComboBox.getItems().addAll(comPorts);
    redirectSystemStreams();
    }

/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Create Stage
 **************************************************************************************************************************/
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LaserControllerUI.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Laser Controller");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    scene.getStylesheets().add(LaserControllerUI.class.getResource("LaserControllerUI.css").toExternalForm());
    // getClass().getResource("resources/Airport.jpg");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Open, Close and check available Comports
 **************************************************************************************************************************/
@FXML
private void checkComPorts() {
    Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();

        if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            comPortComboBox.getItems().addAll(cpi.getName());
            System.out.println(portList);
        }
    }
}

@FXML
public void openComportButton(ActionEvent event) {
    resultsTextArea.setText("Com Port Opened");
    String port = (String)comPortComboBox.getValue();
    //String port = "COM4";
    String rate = (String) baudRateComboBox.getValue();
    String data = (String) dataBitsComboBox.getValue();
    String stop = (String) stopBitsComboBox.getValue();
    int parity = (int) parityComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    int rateInt = Integer.parseInt(rate);
    int dataInt = Integer.parseInt(data);
    int stopInt = Integer.parseInt(stop);

    if (port != null && rate != null && data != null && stop != null) {

        try {
            twoWaySerCom.connect(port, rateInt, dataInt, stopInt, parity);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@FXML
public void closeComportButton(ActionEvent event) {
    resultsTextArea.setText("Com Port Closed");
    try {
        twoWaySerCom.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Up/Down/Left/Right Buttons
 * 
 **************************************************************************************************************************/

@FXML
public void leftButtonPressed(){

        try {
            System.out.println("Left Button pressed, String: " + leftString);
            byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, panLeft, speedNormal, 0x00, endTx, 0x2B };
            TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
            twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
            sw.out.write(command);
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    } 


@FXML
public void leftButtonReleased(){
try {
    System.out.println("Left Button released, String: " + stopString);
    byte[] command = {
        (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) endTx, 0x0F
    };

    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
    sw.out.write(command);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

@FXML
public void rightButtonPressed(){

        try {
            System.out.println("right Button pressed, String: " + leftString);
            byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, panRight, speedNormal, 0x00, endTx, 0x2B };
            TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
            twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
            sw.out.write(command);
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    } 


@FXML
public void rightButtonReleased(){
try {
    System.out.println("right Button released, String: " + stopString);
    byte[] command = {
        (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) endTx, 0x0F
    };

    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
    sw.out.write(command);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

@FXML
public void upButtonPressed(){

try {
    System.out.println("Up Button pressed, String: " + leftString);
    byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, panUp, speedNormal, 0x00, endTx, 0x2B };
    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
    twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
    sw.out.write(command);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
} 


@FXML
public void upButtonReleased(){
try {
    System.out.println("Up Button released, String: " + stopString);
    byte[] command = {
        (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) endTx, 0x0F
    };

    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
    sw.out.write(command);
      } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     }

   }

@FXML
public void downButtonPressed(){

try {
    System.out.println("Down Button pressed, String: " + leftString);
    byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, panDown, speedNormal, 0x00, endTx, 0x2B };
    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
    twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
    sw.out.write(command);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
   } 


 @FXML
public void downButtonReleased(){
try {
    System.out.println("Down Button released, String: " + stopString);
    byte[] command = {
        (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) endTx, 0x0F
    };

    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
    sw.out.write(command);
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Start Stop Buttons
 * 
 ******************************************************************************    ********************************************/
@FXML
public void startTourButton(ActionEvent event) {
new Timer ().schedule(
        new TimerTask () {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    byte st = presetNo[count];
                   System.out.println( "Start Tour Button pressed, String:  "+st);


                   //this part will run from 0 to max of presets every counting.
                   count ++;
                   if (count >=MaxCount) count=0;

                  byte[] command = {(byte) startTx, address, byteOne, goPreset, 0x00, st, endTx, 0x0F};                                                                                                 
                TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

            sw.out.write(command);
                } 
           catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }, 0, 5000);

}

public void stopTourButton(ActionEvent event) {
//  Timer.cancel();
}


/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Call and Set Preset Buttons
 **************************************************************************************************************************/

@FXML
public void setPresetButton(ActionEvent event) {
    byte _preset = (Byte) setPresetComboBox.getValue();
    try {
        something = presetNo[_preset - 1];

        byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, setPreset, 0x00, something, endTx, 0x0F };
        TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

        sw.out.write(command);
        System.out.println(something);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@FXML
public void callPresetButton(ActionEvent event) {
    byte _preset = (byte) getPresetComboBox.getValue();

    try {
        something = presetNo[_preset - 1];

        byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, goPreset, 0x00, something, endTx, 0x0F };
        TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(something);
        sw.out.write(command);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Date Time Picker for the start date
 **************************************************************************************************************************/
@FXML
public void dateTimePickerStart(){
    CalendarPicker dateTime = new CalendarPicker();
    dateTime.withCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());
    dateTime.withShowTime(Boolean.TRUE);
    dateTime.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    dateTime.calendarProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Calendar>() {

        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Calendar> ov, Calendar t, Calendar t1) {
            System.out.println("Selected date: "+t1.getTime().toString());
            startTimeLabel.setText(t1.getTime().toString());
        }
    });
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(dateTime);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 350);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setTitle("Select Time");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * Date Time Picker for the end date
 **************************************************************************************************************************/
@FXML
public void dateTimePickerEnd(){
    CalendarPicker dateTime = new CalendarPicker();
    dateTime.withCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());
    dateTime.withShowTime(Boolean.TRUE);
    dateTime.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    dateTime.calendarProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Calendar>() {

        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Calendar> ov, Calendar t, Calendar t1) {
            System.out.println("Selected date: "+t1.getTime().toString());
            endTimeLabel.setText(t1.getTime().toString());
        }
    });
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(dateTime);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 350);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setTitle("Select Time");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**************************************************************************************************************************
 * to Redirect System Streams to the text area
 **************************************************************************************************************************/
@FXML
public void redirectSystemStreams() {
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
        @Override

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));

}

public void updateTextArea(final String text) {
    Platform.runLater(new java.lang.Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            resultsTextArea.appendText(text);
        }
    });
}

String stopString = "A0,00,00,00,00,00,AF,0F";
String downString = "A0,00,00,10,20,00,AF,2B";
String leftString = "A0,00,00,04,20,00,AF,2B";
String rightString = "A0, 00,00,02,20,00,AF,2B";
String upString = "A0,00,00,08,20,00,AF,2B";
String[] comPorts = {"COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6","COM7", "COM7", "COM9", "COM10",};
String[] parity = { "none", "odd", "even", };
String[] baudRates = { "2400", "4800", "9600", "14400", "19200", "38400", "56000", "115200" };
String[] stopBits = { "0", "1" };
String[] dataBits = { "7", "8" };
byte presetNo[] = { 0X01, 0X02, 0X03, 0X04, 0X05 };
byte something;
Byte[] preset = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int count = 0;
int MaxCount = presetNo.length;
byte startTx = (byte) 0xA0;
byte endTx = (byte) 0xAF;
byte address = 0x00;
byte byteOne = 0x00;
byte setPreset = 0x03;
byte goPreset = 0x07;
byte panRight = 0x02;
byte panLeft = 0x04;
byte panUp = 0x08;
byte panDown = 0x10;
byte speedNormal = 0x20;
}
```

Comment: post your code.... you are missing a closing ) brace in your code somewhere...

Comment: make sure all your opened braces have a corresponding closing brace

Comment: Which Code? the .java where my main is? It runs fine in windows.

Comment: yea that code... Let me or anyone else check it out... It is a syntax error so there is definitely some ) missing somewhere...

Comment: maybe while copying you clipped some brace...

Comment: Ok posted code.  I copied over my whole workspace rather than copy paste actual code.

Comment: i hope the ` before the first line is a mistake... anyway checking out your code :)

Comment: Yes that was me trying to add a code block. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120804/discussion-between-kushan-and-display-name).

Answer (score 0):

> `/opt/jre/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java: 1: /opt/jre/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")`

This is not an error in your program but in your JDK installation. Sounds like `/opt/jre/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java` is an invalid shell script - which is a bit strange because at least on x86_64 Oracle JDK, this should be an binary executable, not a script.

I'd suggest re-installing the correct JDK for your machine.